# Windows Phone 8.1 Keyboard Freezing (Skype/Whatsapp/Viber/SMS)

Tags: keyboard, lumia-925, developer-preview

I'm on a Lumia 925 and developer preview - this morning a strange thing happened...

When I open any messenger of any sort, and start to type, the keyboard pops up and allows me to write one word only before refusing to accept any more inputs (they keys show 'pressed') - only way to write another word is to close the keyboard and pop it up again.

Massively annoying - can't find anything on it anywhere!
Help!

Comment: Just to say I've tried reboot/reset etc, the problem happens the second you use the space key, then they keyboard fails to work.

Comment: Did you do a softreset, holding down your power and volume-down button for ~10 sec?

Comment: Yes I've tried that, same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a resolution here; http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wppeople/keyboard-freezes-after-adding-a-space/1d4b902d-f776-4183-993a-b4b6f0560d98

If you disable the 'suggest / correct' words in keyboard settings it will work again.

Comment: Strange. I'm in the latest build and not problems happen.

Comment: I'm on the latest build too but it is, turning off suggested words is a pain!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the bug is fixed when you disable the "type as I swipe" feature. You can still leave the suggestion/correction feature on, which is much more useful in my opinion.

Surprised that the bug is still not fixed after so many months of updates.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed uninstalling the keyboards and then re-installing it.

On my WP I have 2 keyboards, English and Spanish. This is how I solve the issue:

1. settings > keyboard > uninstall English keyboard.
2. re-install english keyboard.
3. uninstall spanish keyboard.
4. re-install spanish keyboard.
5. shut down your phone.
6. remove the battery
7. install the battery and turn on your phone.
8. problem should be solved.